# ExecutorService only run most recently added Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor, executors

I have a single threaded executor service for fetching some data over the network.

As the user is typing in a search box I am enqueuing possible network tasks. What I want is to cancel all previous requests and only enqueue and immediately run the latest one.

My current approach is to override execute() and submit() methods and clear the queue before calling super.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't get it, why don't you save the `Future` returned on posting a callable to the service, and then `cancel()` the future if you don't want it to be executed.

e.g.

```
Future f1 = service.submit(some_task);

// later

f1.cancel(true); // will interrupt if running...
```

Cleaner IMO...

Comment: As the user is typing more and more requests are enqueued. I want to SKIP all these requests and only run the last one queued.

Comment: @dnkoutso, right, so save all the futures in a list, and cancel all previous ones before adding the new one...